# Can you use javascript to modify onmousedown of div at runtime

Tags: javascript, events

I want to write some JavaScript that will change the onmousedown of a div at runtime.  So on load a mouse down on the div will do one thing and if a JavaScript function is called a mouse down on the div will do something else.  Is this possible?

Comment: @ mrjrdnthms : What Prestaul is attaching to the handler is the definition of a new function. What you are attaching is the return of the alert function, that is void/undefined, IIRC. This is why is code works, and your won't.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just assign the onMouseDown property.

```
document.getElementById('myDiv').onmousedown = function() {
  alert('New mouse down handler.');
};
```

Keep in mind that javascript properties are case-sensitive.  "onmousedown" is all lower-case.

Comment: That was it, thanks...  I was trying     document.getElementById('myDiv').onMouseDown = alert('test');
You have an idea why that doesn't work?

Comment: Event handler properties in javascript must be assigned functions that act as handlers.  When you assign event handler attributes inline in your html you do not use a function definition... Just one of those things!

Comment: no idea why this event handler doesnt call if i click on some div?? i have no idea.:/..